# Community vs Site URL

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android

Most of the documentation around setting up the mobile SDK references utilizing the community URL. We currently use a Site rather than a community and have been trying to use that site url instead of a community url. With this we get a "301 Moved Permanently" response.

Is there any issue using the site URL as opposed to a community URL as per the documentation?